# Using Playa passing values

Tags: ee2, categories, templates, playa

I am trying the following with no luck

```
<?php $category = "{exp:cat2:id category_url_title='{segment_4}'}"; ?>
{exp:playa:parents channel="article|blogs|calendar_events|contests|podcasts|videos" category="<?= $category ?>" field="show" limit="24"}

    // Do something here

{/exp:playa:parents}
```

This is wrapped by `{exp:channel:entries}` tag. Now If I provide the value of `category` hard coded it returns the results but not if I pass it in like the above. Even if I assign the value of $category = '2' it wont return any results. Any ideas ?

Comment: this may be a parse order related issue. If the code works when hard coded, then I suspect that the php variable is not being inserted at the time that its needed.  Are you able to rework your tags/code to do away with the php?

perhaps Low seg2cat would work better and allow you to use the segment/category variable directly in the playa tags?

Comment: @pixldev Yes that is exactly the problem. I have removed php code and used cat2 directly and also set `parse="inward"` on playa expression and it worked.

Comment: @DeepakSK. If it solved out your issue, can you provide your solution to answer and mark it accepted so others can get help?

Comment: @MufaddalNala Have posted it.. will accept it when it allows me to.

Comment: Good job.. keep it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved this by adding the option `parse="inward"` to the `{exp:playa:parents}` tag. So my code looks like below

```
{exp:playa:parents  channel="article|blogs|calendar_events|contests|podcasts|videos" category="YOUR_DYNAMIC VALUE FROM PHP OR ANOTHER TAG" field="show" limit="24" parse="inward"}

    // Do something here

{/exp:playa:parents}
```

The above code worked as long as there is no pagination required inside the `playa:parents` block. For pagination to work you need to provide `var_prefix="your_prefix"` option but then it will have to modify the code to reference your variables based on the prefix set. I avoided that by using embed. So basically you can put the whole Playa code inside another file and embed them where you want to use it. So the playa code will look something like below

```
{exp:playa:parents  channel="article|blogs|calendar_events|contests|podcasts|videos" category="YOUR_DYNAMIC VALUE FROM PHP OR ANOTHER TAG" field="show" limit="24" entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"}

    // Do something here

{/exp:playa:parents}
```

Note I have removed the parse option and added entry_id option which should be same as the parent entry ID you are trying to find the parents for.

Hope that helps!